# Swift - Navigation Bars

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, iphone-x

I am having trouble making it so that the navigation bar will have an optimised display for both the iPhone X and all other iPhones and iPads.

I have read on the apple developer documentation that the navigation bar is meant to adapt so that the title is not hidden by the sensor housing on the iPhone X.

I have therefore tried making a navigation bar as normal on an iPhone 8 on the Interface Builder (and adding height 65 constraints, as well as top, left and right attachment constraints).

When I run in the simulator, the iPhone X shows the navigation bar through the sensor housing, thus meaning the title isn't visible.

Any help on how to get navigation bars working for all iPhones and iPads and the iPhone X at the same time would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 11 you are supposed to be using the new safe area guides to position your content.  Do not assume a bar size as an offset from your view.  See the apple documentation on [Positioning Content Relative to the Safe Area](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area)